# Laravel. Настройка поддоменов, или как даботает Route::domain()

Tags: php, laravel

Есть такие роуты:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.' . 'site.ru')->group(function($subdomain)
{
    Route::get('/', function() { /* */ })->name('subdomainIndex');
    Route::get('/login', function() { /* */ })->name('subdomainLogin');

   /* etc. */
}
```

При этом эти поддомены создаются из админки, храянятся в базе. (Пользователи - новый - задайте поддомен для пользователя...).

1. Как настроить apache/nginx (есть возможность использовать любой), чтобы он ловил любой поддомен (*.site.ru)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев на ваш код, заметил ошибку в контроллере. Пересмотрите [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing), где указано, как использовать поддомены в своих роутах

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Видно, что динамический поддомен передается непосредственно перед URI-параметрами напрямую в обработчик роута (не группы!)

Далее вам обязательно нужно добавить в DNS домена А-запись `*.site.ru` (короче - поддомен `*`). Делается это по-разному в зависимости от вашего DNS редактора.

Что касается настроек сервера, то никаких дополнительных настроек не нужно, кроме тех, которые рекомендуются в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/#web-server-configuration). Смысл в том, чтобы все запросы к приложению шли на `public/index.php`